# How to get subsite with custom template to inherit background from parent site without activating SharePoint Server Publishing in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, solution-package, sub-site

When I activate SharePoint Server Publishing it takes away my ability to create new templates that would later be stored in my solutions as `.wsp` files.  Is there a way to get a subsite to inherit from the parent without activating Sharepoint Server Publishing so I can retain the templates.  Plus I heard that even after you deactivate Sharepoint Server Publishing you still can't get back some features that go way when you activate it.

Comment: What do you mean by subsite to inherit from parent? Are you talking about permissions or the theme/master page?

Comment: I should have been more clear.  Master page is what I want but that option is not available nor is design manager without enabling share point server publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Master page link is only available when you activate the SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure feature. But there is a hack you can go directly to the url
http:///_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx and change the master page for any site.

For the solution of your problem, you can create root site which points to suppose master.master file as an example. Then you can create a subsite and select the master page as inherited from parent. You can save this site as template and even change master page using the url hack provided above.